Internet connection is regularly throttled to zero unless I open a game in Steam
This has been a problem since upgrading to Windows 11.
My internet throttles itself to the point of being unusable - essentially not connected, though the wifi panel shows no problems or warnings. To temporarily fix the issue I can restart my network adapter, but it barely lasts a few minutes.
I have updated drivers, have tried the various ntsh and ipconfig commands that are recommended, and have ensured WLAN AutoConfig and WWAN AutoConfig are set to automatic in Windows services.
Nothing resolves it.
Today I found that the only time I have a clean, unbroken internet connection is when I have a game opened via Steam. I suspect this might point to the root of the problem, but I'm unsure where to go from here.
Potentially useful information:
IPV4 and IPV6 are turned on.
Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Protocol is turned off (I'm not sure what this is - useful?)
Power management for all network adapters is turned off.

Is the issue WiFi only, or Ethernet, too?

@DrMoishePippik I don't have any means to try ethernet. It occurs on any WiFi connection (I tried tethering to my phone and it similarly dropped to 0)

+1 Good test using phone. Perhaps try another OS, e.g., Win 10 on Win2USB, or Linux (Ubuntu Live on USB, for example). If that runs full speed, then I'd suggest reinstalling Win 11 and testing again. Did you have to make any hacks to force Win 11 on your PC?

@DrMoishePippik Reinstalling Win11 feels like quite a destructive task just to fix a network issue, I'm reluctant to try that yet. I didn't need to hack anything to make Win11 install, it was an automatic update a couple of years ago.

Reinstalling from the latest MS ISO, keeping files, is not too long a process, often not much more than SFC/DISM repair. That said, though it's like swatting a fly with a mallet, sometimes it is the best or only way to fix an operating system error. However, did you confirm it's not hardware-related by booting an alternate OS (no installation needed)?

@DrMoishePippik How can it be hardware related if the problem goes away immediately when I have a game running in Steam?
